# How to find QTP Concurrent Licence Expiration Date

Tags: qtp

We are using QTP concurrent licence for our project. I just want to know how to find the expiration date of QTP license.
I have browsed different forums and found out that "Wladmin" utility will show the expiration date of QTP license. But that utility is not displaying any information in our client machine. 
Can you please say me 
1. How to find the expiration date of QTP license in client machine 
2. Let me know where this "Wladmin" utility is available 
3. and if we require admin privileges to run "Wladmin" utility.

Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the QTP install disk, you´ll find a "LicenseServer" directory with a "utils" subdirectory. There, you will find `LSMON`.**

If you launch it from the command prompt, it should find any reachable license server and display some info (probably more than you ever wanted to see) about them.

You might need to pass the name of your license server on the command line.

That´s the cheapest way to display the floating license details on a client.

**An alternative is to use `WlmAdmin.exe`** from the same directory, which basically is a GUI version of `lsmon`.